# State not changing for nested attribute with DateTimePickerModal React Native Expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using the datepicker that was authorized by expo for my react native project. The problem I'm having is, its the only element that is not saving the value to my nested object state. I have no issue with doing it for the other inputs in my component. I tried using the spread operation, but I get back a warning stating that the object is undefined. How can I update the state of my nested object with the date input?

```
   this.state = {
          isDatePickerVisible: false,
          applicant_form: {
             user_id: '',
             personal_info_attributes: {
               dob: '' // won't update with date
              }
        } 
 }


handleConfirm = (date) => {
     // doesn't save state
     this.setState({ applicant_form: {personal_info_attributes: {dob: date}}})
     this.setState({isDatePickerVisible: false})
  }

   showDatePicker = () => {
    this.setState({isDatePickerVisible: true})
  }
  
  hideDatePicker = () => {
    this.setState({isDatePickerVisible: false})
   }


 <View>
    <Button title="Select DOB" onPress={this.showDatePicker} />
       <DateTimePickerModal
          isVisible={this.state.isDatePickerVisible}
          mode="date"
          onConfirm={this.handleConfirm}
          onCancel={this.hideDatePicker}
          headerTextIOS="Select DOB"
       />
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct state `key` is not being referenced in your `setState` function. You can try this

```
 handleConfirm = (date) => {
    // doesn't save state
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      applicant_form: {
        ...this.state.applicant_form,
        personal_info_attributes: {
          ...this.state.applicant_form.personal_info_attributes,
          dob: date,
        },
      },
    });
    this.setState({ isDatePickerVisible: false });
  };
```

Comment: After putting the console warn before the final set state & it certainly showed the value. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome @valcod3r, please don't forget to also mark the answer as accepted if it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your variable naming is consistent.
It is `applicant_form` in the state and `candidate_form` in `setState` method

Comment: I was testing another component at the time.